# Can't initialize static QList?

Tags: c++, qt, static

I get the following error:

`Cube.cpp:10: error: expected initializer before ‘<<’ token`

Here's the important parts of the header file:

```
#ifndef CUBE_H
#define CUBE_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <iostream>

#define YELLOW 0
#define RED 1
#define GREEN 2
#define ORANGE 3
#define BLUE 4
#define WHITE 5

using namespace std;

class Cube {
public:
  ...
  static QList<int> colorList;
  ...
};
#endif
```

Here's the line that gives the error:

```
QList<int> Cube::colorList << YELLOW << RED << GREEN << ORANGE << BLUE << WHITE;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't initialize an object with `<<`. The `=` that is usually there is not `operator=()` -- it's a special syntax that is essentially the same as calling a constructor.

Something like this might work

```
QList<int> Cube::colorList = EmptyList() << YELLOW << RED << GREEN << ORANGE << BLUE << WHITE;
```

where EmptyList() is

```
QList<int> EmptyList()
{
   QList<int> list;
   return list;
}
```

and is a copy construction of a list, and barring some optimization, a copy of the list that is created.

Comment: Thanks. I used something similar to what you've provided. Instead of empty list, I used new QList<int>() << ...; It seems to work. Do you see any potential issues in using this method?

Comment: Just that you are creating a list and then copying it.  For such a short list and for just once in the app, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

That line is not a initialization/definition of QList Cube::colorList. It is invoking insertion operator on an object which is not yet defined namely (QList Cube::colorList).

I don't know QT and hence can't comment on how to really initialize this class.