# How to store data in QMap & Qlist in QT?

Tags: qt, qlist, qmap

How to store data in QMap & Qlist and retrieve them in QT ?

My requirement is I have Schedule Name which are Monday - Sunday and Schedule Items like "Sunday , 12:00 - 17:30".........

Now I want to have 2 QlistWidget one contains schedule names and other contains Schedule items , now when i select one Schedule name in first listbox corresponding related schedule item gets listed in another listbox.

How can I add items to listwidget using Qmap and Qlist?

How to keep data in memory using it?

```
  QList<QString> ScheduleItemslist;
     ScheduleItemslist << "Saturday,09:00- 17:30" << "Sunday,10:00- 12:00" << "Sunday,01:30- 17:30" ;

 QList<QString> ScheduleItemslst;
  ScheduleItemslst << "Monday,09:00- 17:30" << "Tuesday,10:00- 12:00" << "Wednesday,01:30- 17:30" ;


QMap<QString,QList<QString> > map;
map["Weekend Plus"] = ScheduleItemslist ;
map["All"] = ScheduleItemslst ;

foreach (QString key, map.keys())
{
    ui->listWidgetTimeSet->addItem (key) ;
}


ui->listWidgetTime->addItems(ScheduleItemslist);
```

In ItemselectionChanged Event :

```
QList<QString> ScheduleItemslist;
     ScheduleItemslist << "Saturday,09:00- 17:30" << "Sunday,10:00- 12:00" << "Sunday,01:30- 17:30" ;

  QList<QString> ScheduleItemslst;
    ScheduleItemslst << "Monday,09:00- 17:30" << "Tuesday,10:00- 12:00" << "Wednesday,01:30- 17:30" ;

if(ui->listWidgetTimeSet->currentItem()->text() == "Weekend Plus")
{
    ui->listWidgetTime->addItems(ScheduleItemslist);
}
else if (ui->listWidgetTimeSet->currentItem()->text() == "All")
{
    ui->listWidgetTime->addItems(ScheduleItemslst);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this to store your data.

```
//Declare your map
QMap <QString, QList <QString> > map;

//Populate your map in a function
void populateMap ()
{

    QList<QString> sundaylist;
    sundaylist<< "Sunday , 12:00 - 17:30" << "Sunday , 18:00 - 20:30";
    map ["Sunday"] = sundaylist;

    QList<QString> mondaylist;
    mondaylist<< "Monday , 12:00 - 17:30" << "Monday , 18:00 - 20:30";
    map ["Monday"] = mondaylist        
}

//Populate list1 with keys in your map
void populateList1 ()
{
    list1.addItems (map.keys ());
}

//This is your slot connected to currentItemChanged  signal of list1
void list1CurrentItemChanged ( QListWidgetItem * current, QListWidgetItem * previous ) 
{
    list2.clear ();
    QString key = current->text ();
    list2.addItems (map [key]);

}
```

Comment: @OrcunC : Now how to add this data to Qlistwidget at run time ?

Comment: After you populated your map, iterate over keys and add them to first list as below. foreach (QString key, map.keys ()) {firstwidget->addItem (key)} Then connect a slot to currentItemChanged() or currentRowChanged() signal. currentItemChanged () seems like a better option. Get the text of item and use as key to populat the second list as I have shown above.

Comment: @OrcunC : pls see my posted code above . is that Ok or any changes required ?

Comment: I don't have a compiler right now with me but I added pseudo code so that at least you can see what you need to do. I hope this helps

Comment: @OrcunC : One more Help how to initialize QList<QString> list to default ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. A line like QList<QString> mylist will construct mylist variable as an empty list. Is that what you mean ? If you need to initialize a static QList read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320677/cant-initialize-static-qlist

Comment: No in my header file to my constructor when i am passing QList<QString> list it says default argument missing for Qlist<Qstring> list

Comment: thanks to your example I found my fault, so `QMap <QString, QList<QString>>` is different from `QMap <QString, QList<QString> >`, if not add space causes the following error: `'>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list`, Thanks +1 for your answer!